# Response string cut to 2033 characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created an application in C# (ASP.NET MVC) and it works very well in Visual Studio, but when I install it in IIS, the calls to ajax only return 2033 characters.

I already put this in `web.config` (but it does not work):

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>

<system.web>
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="500000000"  executionTimeout="120" />
</system.web>
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: You need to translate the first line into English very soon otherwise your question maybe removed.

Comment: Sorry, its done :)

Comment: @JorgeLuis if you want to post the question in spanish, do it in [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

What version of IIS you are using? I suspect it is below 8, probably 7 or 7.5 then this issue is known and related to IIS.
Better use upgraded version.